# How to order by attribute name?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Need a bit help with sorting attributes inside of element of array.
so I have such payload:

```
person=[
 {
   "Phone" : "1234",
   "Name" : "John",
   "Address": "ABC"
 },
 {
   "Phone" : "5678",
   "Name" : "Mary",
   "Address": "DEF"
 },
]
```

and I expecting to got it like this:

```
 person=[
 {
   "Address": "ABC",
   "Name" : "John",
   "Phone" : "1234"
 },
 {
   "Address": "DEF",
   "Name" : "Mary",
   "Phone" : "5678"
 },
]
```

I try as that:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
"result": payload[0] orderBy $$
```

but its not sorted, if I try to use

> orderBy $

I got error: You cannot compare a value if type ::object...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map each element, then order each one:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
"result": payload map ($ orderBy $$)
```

Output:

```
{
  "result": [
    {
      "Address": "ABC",
      "Name": "John",
      "Phone": "1234"
    },
    {
      "Address": "DEF",
      "Name": "Mary",
      "Phone": "5678"
    }
  ]
}
```